# VSCode: single-line JS object to multi-line one

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

That's quite often for me that I need to change my single-line JS object to a multi-line one. Such as:

```
var obj = { prop1: 'abc', prop2: 123, prop3: 'something else' }

 |          |
 v          v

var obj = {
  prop1: 'abc',
  prop2: 123,
  prop3: 'something else'
}
```

Is there some shortcut for doing such a thing in VSCode? Or is there some way to create such a shortcut?

Comment: Ctrl H to replace "', " in selection with a line break and save to let vs code indents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the "split line" plugin.
See here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chenzhe.split-line

[image]

Comment: Tried this, it doesn't do any auto formatting of JSON - just ostensibly splits on a separator. But I tried to use it splitting on ',' and nothing happened. You need to provide instructions on what to do with it for this to be a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Prettier - Code formatter

Will solve your needs (easily in visual studio code)

`esbenp.prettier-vscode`

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

You can make it format on save, which is very nice.

Comment: how to do the reverse? convert a multi line json into single line , remove trailing whitespaces and line breaks?

Comment: I installed the extension, nothing happened. I ran "Format document", selected Prettier as the formatter for JSON; nothing happened. My JSON object is still a single line.

Answer (score -2):

The right way to do this is to setup ESLint (or prettier) rules, and VSCode will
do this for you automatically on save.